# How to upload an image to a local folder in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I want to upload an image to local folder using vuejs. How do I do it. Although I can display an image like this:

```
<template v-slot:[`item.logo`]="{ item }" >
    <v-avatar size="40">
        <v-img :src="require('@/assets/media/' + item.logo)"></v-img>
    </v-avatar>
</template>
```

this is my code:

```
 <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" ref="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload" >
  .....
 <v-btn color="primary" dark text @click="save">Save</v-btn>
```

here is my script:

```
handleFileUpload(e){
var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
if (!files.length) return;

this.createImage(files[0]);
},

createImage(file) {
  var image = new Image();
  console.log(image);
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var vm = this;

  reader.onload = (e) => {
    vm.image = e.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},

save() {
 let formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('file', this.file);

  axios.post( 'src/assets/media',
    formData,
    {
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }
  ).then(function(){
    console.log('SUCCESS!!');
  })
  .catch(function(){
    console.log('FAILURE!!');
  });
}
```

I want to store the images in src/assets/media. But I get this error `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module './'"`

Answer (score 0):

You need an app on the server to save the image I don't think it is possible to save it in the front app, You can temporarily save it in base 64 in localsotrage

```
imgData = createBase64Image(img);
localStorage.setItem("imgData", imgData);

function createBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```